# Parsing JSON data to an array

Tags: objective-c, json

I get the following error whenI launch my app

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
    reason: '-   [COViewController fetchAppNetData]: unrecognized selector 
    sent to instance 0x716d200'
```

Basically I am unable to find out how to parse the JSON data to my array. The structure of my JSON is as follows

```
{

  "meta": {},

  "data": []

}
```

I know that `meta` is a dictionary and `data` is an array. But when I try to use the following piece of code I get the above error

```
- (void)fetchAppNetData:(NSData *)responseData
{
 //parse JSON data
 NSError *error;
 NSDictionary* appNet_json = [NSJSONSerialization 
    JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
 NSArray* appNetTimeline = [[appNet_json objectForKey:@"meta"] 
    objectForKey:@"data"];
 NSLog(@"AppNet Timeline : %@",appNetTimeline);
}
```

How do I make sure that I can identify the structure of JSON properly next time, so that I can avoid this sort of issue? I am extremely sorry to come up with such kind of doubts

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with parsing JSON.  `fetchAppNetData` isn't defined in the object you're trying to use to call it.  You never even get into the method.

Comment: I am calling definitely calling it in
`viewdidLoad`

`[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchAppNetData) withObject:appNetData waitUntilDone:YES];`

Comment: Do you notice the `:` on the end of that selector name?  Neither do I.

Comment: (And there's no need to do performSelectorOnMainThread.  viewDidLoad is already in the main thread.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with the content of the method `-fetchAppNetData:`. That method is not even getting called.

The error is saying that you tried to invoke a method of that name on an object that doesn't respond to it. You've sent that message to an instance of class `COViewController`, but that's evidently not the class that implemented the method you posted.

Comment: Caught the error. I forgot to add a `:` at the end of `fetchAppNetData`. Here is the corrected code
`[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchAppNetData:) withObject:appNetData waitUntilDone:YES]; – BarryVenom 57 secs ago edit `

Comment: @BarryVenom -- Why are you doing the performSelector vs just calling the method??

Comment: I had to do so because I wanted to download all the JSON data in the background while the application displays the first view to the user.

Comment: It seems odd that you are shunting data handling to the main thread. Usuallly, you do data parsing on the background thread and UI updates on the main thread. In any case, you might consider switching to GCD, which entails code which the compiler can more readily check. For example: `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [self fetchAppNetData:appNetData]; });` Also, consider if you really need synchronization here. If not, use `dispatch_async()`.